# some properties of Baer groups and A-groups

Tags: group-theory

I am wondering to know more about Baer groups and A-groups.
I know their definition as below:

- A **Baer group** is a group that all elements of prime power order have prime power index $[G:C_G(x)]$
- An **A-group** is a group that all it's sylow subgroup are Abelian.

But I want to know more a bout them. For example are these groups always nilpotent?
If someone introduses a book that can help me, I will really appreciate him/her.

Comment: Are you talking about finite groups? If so, it would be helpful to say!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $S_3$ adheres to both of these properties and is not nilpotent.  I believe [Robinson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387944613) has a good introduction to both of these topics.

Comment: Yes, the groups are finite.